# Get response from insert model in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

This is my controller

```
        $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
        $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        //Loading View
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('post-add', $data);
```

This is my model

```
function form_insert($data){
    //Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college) 
    $this->db->insert('adds', $data); 
}
```

data added to model (insert_model)
and showd message - data insertd successfully

but i want to show message either **SUCESS** or **error**

Answer (score 2):

We can get last inserted id. In **Codeigniter**, last inserted id returns by :

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

I have tried below code & working fine for me.

```
<?php
            $is_insert=$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
            if($is_insert > 0)
               $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
            else
               $data['message'] = 'Error in insert';
            //Loading View
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('post-add', $data);


            function form_insert($data){
               //Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college) 
               $this->db->insert('adds', $data); 
               return $this->db->insert_id();
            }
        ?>
```

for CI reference please check below url:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

Just make some changes in your code, like below:

Controller:-

```
if($this->insert_model->form_insert($data)){
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
}else{
    $data['message'] = 'Error message';
}
//Loading View
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('post-add', $data);
```

Model :-

```
function form_insert($data){
   //Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college) 
   $this->db->insert('adds', $data);
   return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: The whole if statement in the model can be done with 1 line: return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;

Comment: hi.. it doesn't solved problem completely..
suppose i am entering a primary key that is already present in database table so it is giving an error like this

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY'

but i want to give my customized error i.e    $data['message'] = 'Error';

Comment: why are you entering duplicate primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->db->affected_rows();` to check data is insert or not

**In Models**

```
function form_insert($data) {
    //Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college) 
    $this->db->insert('adds', $data);
    $afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
    if ($afftectedRows > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$insert = $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
if ($insert) {
    $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
} else {
    $data['message'] = 'Error';
}
//Loading View
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('post-add', $data);
```

Comment: thanks alot, one thing more i wan to ask you.. will it give error if mysql is not ready or error in database connection???

Comment: To check database connection error check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483861/codeigniter-php-check-if-can-connect-to-database

Comment: yea thanks dear.. i am new to mvc so confused alott, may i have your skype id?

Answer (score 0):

model

```
function form_insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('adds', $data);

    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
if (form_insert == true){
    $data['message'] = 'success';
} else {
    $data['message'] = 'error';
}
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('post-add', $data);
```