# CodeIgniter 3 database connection load error check return value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got an issue in live server for CodeIgniter 3 project. I need to get a return value of database connection error

```
if($this->load->database('default',TRUE)===FALSE){ .... }
```

It shows this error:

[image]

I only need to return value check (*e.g connected ok or not (boolean) TRUE/FALSE)*).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter/PHP check if can connect to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483861/codeigniter-php-check-if-can-connect-to-database)

Comment: Nop I checked already these pages nothing is suitable for this issue

Comment: You could try a [database ping](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php) operation.

Comment: this isn't a Codeigniter way to check error

Comment: Please add the error as text not as a screenshot!

Comment: I think it will do the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found so far, change the codeigniter environment in index.php from 'development' to 'production' then it will return error instead of displaying this error.[image]

This is a codeigniter problem.  I couldn't check error If I want to work in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you. please into the link
http://www.joshuawinn.com/launching-your-codeigniter-site-disable-database-errors/

Comment: checked it but I want this error to return me a value true or false not disable database error. but it gives me a hint.