# How to check controller error on sending data or database error load?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, database-connection

Im new on web I still learn using this CI platform. I want to know how to check connection to database that I choose from file "database.php" wrong or check controller wrong.

I try to read the guide in CI but im not find how to select database in there.

I hope there is place for checking my controller or database.

```js
function clearagentdetails() {
        $('#txt_agent_name').val('');
  $('#txt_agent_phone').val('');
  $('#txt_agent_email').val('');
        $('#txtMainAgtID').val('');
 }

$("#btnGenCobrokedetails").click(function () {
        getagentdetails($('#txt_agent_nik').val(), $('#ddl_principal').val());
        return false;
    });
 
function getagentdetails($agent_nik, $principal) {

        clearagentdetails();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {agent_nik: $agent_nik, principal: $principal},
            url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/secondary/get_agentdetails1'; ?>',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if ($.trim(data.astatus) != 'Active') {
                    $('#txt_agent_name').attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#lblCobrokeMsg").text('The agent status is ' + data.astatus);
                    $("#divCobrokeWarning").show();
                } else {
                    $("#lblCobrokeMsg").text('The agent status is ' + data.astatus);
                    $("#divCobrokeWarning").show();
                    $('#txt_agent_name').val(data.actname);
                    $('#txt_agent_phone').val(data.phone);
                    $('#txt_agent_email').val(data.email);
                    $('#txtMainAgtID').val(data.agentid);
                    $('#ddl_listing').attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
//Controller Function
function get_agentdetails1() {
        $agentic =  $this->db->escape($this->input->post('agent_nik'));
        $principal =  $this->db->escape($this->input->post('principal'));
        $rs         = $this->secondary_model->get_agentic_select1($agentic,$principal);
        if ($rs->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           $row = $rs->row(); 
           $agentid = $row->agentid;
           $agentic = $row->agentic;
           $propnexid = $row->propnexid;
           $actname= $row->actname;
           $astatus = $row->astatus;
           $phone = $row->Phone;
           $email = $row->PrtEmail;
        }
        echo json_encode(array(
            "agentid" => $agentid,
            "agentic" => $agentic,
            "propnexid" => $propnexid,
            "actname" => "hahah",
            "astatus"=> "active",//"$astatus,
            "phone"=> $phone,
            "email"=> $email));
    }
    
    
//Model Function
function get_agentic_select1($agentic,$principal) {
        $a = $this->load->database('db_001', TRUE);
        $rs=$this->db->query("EXEC v2_AgentDetails @pAgentIC= $agent_nik ");
        $this->db->close();
        return $rs;
    }
```

```html
<label>Agent ID<span style="color: red; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" minlength="16" maxlength="16" id="txt_agent_nik" name="txt_agent_nik" class="form-control required">
<label>Principal<span style="color: red; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="txt_agent_nik" name="txt_agent_nik" class="form-control required">

<a href="#" id="btnGenCobrokedetails"><span class="icon-arrow-right-3">Check Agent</span></a>
```

Comment: **don't post MySQL host & passwords on public**

Comment: This Question Related to this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483861/codeigniter-php-check-if-can-connect-to-database)